# Relationship between hamming weight and number of codewords of a binary code

Tags: coding-theory

Set $ N_c (i,4)$ as the number of codewords in a binary code C with hamming weights congruent to $i$ module $4$. Assuming C is of length $n$ and dimension $k$, how can it be proved that if $C$ is an $[n,k]$-code with $k \ge 4 $ that $ N_c (i,4)$ is even $\forall i \in0,1,2,3 $.

i know that $N_c (0,4) + N_c (2,4)$ is the sum of all even weighted elements  and $N_c (1,4) + N_c (3,4)$ is the sum of all odd weighted elements. I was planning to perform an induction on $n$  starting with $k = 4$ but i dont know how to continue.Any suggestions? thanks a great deal.

By the way, is it safe for me to assume that either $ \{N_c (0,4) + N_c (2,4)\} = |C|$ or $N_c (0,4) + N_c (2,4) = N_c (1,4) + N_c (3,4) = 2^{k-1} ?$ - with no restrictions on $k$

Comment: The assumption in your last sentence is perfectly safe to make. It follows from the observation that the sum of two codewords of even weight is a codeword of even weight. You might want to prove this for yourself, and then try to extend this notion further rather than go with induction on $n$.

Comment: hi, by extend on this notion further, in what direction should i extend it?

Comment: i already proved that the sum of two codewords of even weight is a codeword of even weight but that is not affected by the value of k at all. or am i mistaken?